# Formatting SQL query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a query for my PostgreSQL database.

I think the format of my query is wrong and I can't seem to get it to work, I have posted my code below:

```
 query = cur.execute('SELECT "KINASE_NAME" FROM public."Phosphosite_table"
    WHERE "GENE_NAME" LIKE %(genename)s AND "RESIDUE" LIKE %(location)s')
```

The aim is to take the kinase name is the gene name and location match.

my error message appears as the following:

```
    ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9eae43b913d6> in <module>()
     35 cur = connection.cursor()
     36 
---> 37 query = cur.execute('SELECT "KINASE_NAME" FROM public."Phosphosite_table" WHERE "GENE_NAME" LIKE%(genename)s AND "RESIDUE" LIKE %(location)s')
```

Thanks!

Connor

Comment: Sorry, just to add, the variable is a list of strings that contain numbers within the strings if that helps.

Comment: Please tag your request with the API you are using. According to Lutz Horn it is psycopg (or psycopg2)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string operations to build SQL queries. [Use the proper `%s` syntax](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html).

```py
genname = "foo"
location = "bar"
cur.execute("SELECT ... LIKE %s and ... LIKE %s", (genname, location))
```

No quotes around the *values* must be used. The quoting will be done by the DB API library.

Comment: Thank you, Lutz, for your response. I tried the code that you posted: cur.execute('SELECT "KINASE_NAME" FROM public."Phosphosite_table" LIKE %s and LIKE %s', (genename, location)). and got an error: ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-d21250cd0d10> in <module>()
 
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "LIKE"
LINE 1: ...ECT "KINASE_NAME" FROM public."Phosphosite_table" LIKE '[''1...

Comment: `... FROM public."Phosphosite_table" WHERE "GENE_NAME" LIKE ...`